# Mutexes with variables in struct

Tags: multithreading, struct, alignment, mutex, atomic

I'm working on a project that uses multiples threads which can access a shared struct containing multiple variables.

To avoid concurrency problems, I use mutexes whenever a write is made to one of the variables inside the shared struct. Right now I use a different mutex for each variable, so that I avoid locking a thread for trying to write to a variable that is not being written to, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to avoid this problem.

Also, considering that my struct has uint16_t variables, is there any additional measures I should take to guarantee data consistency across threads because of memory alignment and multiple variables stored on the same data register?

Thanks.

Comment: "...but I'd like to know if there is a better way to avoid this problem." - Using **single mutex** for all variables, because it is **simpler**. Note, that before optimize performance, you need to measure that performance first, as usual. As for accessing different structure fields from different mutexes, see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008183/race-condition-when-accessing-adjacent-members-in-a-shared-struct-according-to.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what language.  I'm going to pretend it's C++.

> I use a different mutex for each variable...

That sounds suspicious.

Your threads communicate with each other by updating shared state.  A mutex, when correctly used, does two things:

- It ensures that after thread A updates the shared state, other threads will be able to see what was changed, and
- It ensures that the other threads will *not* see the change until the change is *complete*.

If a thread can meaningfully change the state of the program by writing a single `uint16_t` value, then you don't need a mutex for that.  Just change the type of the variable to `atomic<uint16_t>.`  Making it atomic will ensure that other threads can see the change.  And, you don't have to worry about the completeness.  That's trival: Every other thread must either see the old value or the new value. There's no other possibilities.

You need a `mutex` when the situation is more complicated.  Suppose you have three variables:

```
int a, b, c;
```

And, suppose that there's a rule, that `a+b+c` must always equal zero.  A rule like that is called an *invariant*.  Now, there's no way a thread can legally change just one of those three variables.  But, if it tries to change two of them in a row, there's always the possibility that some other thread could look at them at just the wrong moment, and it could see them in an inconsistent state (i.e., in a state that breaks the invariant.)

Making the variables `atomic` won't fix the problem.  And, *making a separate mutex for each variable* **won't** fix the problem.  You need *one* mutex whose purpose is to protect the invariant.  You need every thread that updates `a`, `b`, and/or `c` to lock that one mutex whenever it's making a change; and you need every thread that expects the invariant to be true to lock the same mutex whenever it *looks* at them.